# wrong output in sort + find bigges in Array

Tags: c, arrays

Today I created a program which have 3 Functions:

**sortArray(array,length);

removeDuplicateInArray(array, length);

max = findMax(array, length);**

The program works fine but, if I run it more times let say, three times, the output is only one OK, other two is different and i think that somehow has to do with the length of the array in findMax function, because i remove duplicates and the array does not have the same size . I'm not sure if there is the problem.

The program is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sortArray(int *array, int length){
    int i, j, k, temp;

    for(i=0;i<length-1;i++){
        for(k=0;k<length-i-1;k++){
            if(array[k]<array[k+1]){
                temp=array[k];
                array[k]=array[k+1];
                array[k+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(j=0;j<length;j++){
        printf("%d ",array[j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

void removeDuplicateInArray(int *array, int length){
    int i,j,k;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < length;j++) {
         if (array[j] == array[i]) {
            for (k = j; k < length; k++) {
               array[k] = array[k + 1];
            }
            length--;
         }else{
            j++;
         }
      }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      printf("%d ", array[i]);
   }
   printf("\n\n");
}

int findMax(int *array, int length){
    int i;
    int max = array[0];

    for(i=1;i<length;i++){
        if(max == array[i]){
            continue;
        }

        if(max<array[i]){
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main(void){
    int array[] = {-9,-7,-3,-1,9,7,3,1,-8,-6,-4,-10,-2,8,6,4,2,5,-5,-10};
    int length = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
    int max;

    sortArray(array,length);
    removeDuplicateInArray(array, length);
    max = findMax(array, length);

    printf("Max = %d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

> ```
> michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program 
> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -10
> ```

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 

Max = 9
michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -10 

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 

Max = 9
michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -10 

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 

Max = 2034093120
michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -10 

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 

Max = 912874208
michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -10 

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 

Max = 1269451840
michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -10 

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 

Max = 1946221408
michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -10 

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 

Max = 9
```

The output should be 9, but the output is not always 9

Comment: instead of passing the array length as a parameter, why not get the length of the array in each function?

Comment: @devlin carnate and how do you get the length of that array if i pass it as pointer ?

Comment: @cad i did that already, or you mean something else ?

Comment: in function: remove....array() this line: 'array[k] = array[k + 1];'will access beyond the upper boundary of the array.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: this line: 'if(array[k]<array[k+1]){' in the sortarray() function is not correct.  It should be: 'if(array[k] > array[k+1]){'  to sort the array ascending

Comment: the function: removeDuplicates() is not helping the algorithm.  It could be eliminated with no loss to functionality.

Comment: these lines: 'if(max == array[i]){
            continue;
        } ' in findMax() are not really helping the algorithm and can be eliminated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `removeDuplicateInArray` function changes the length of the array, but the calling function, `main` in your case, doesn't know about the new length.

You can either return the new length from the function:

```
int removeDuplicateInArray(int *array, int length)
{
    // code as above

    return length;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
length = removeDuplicateInArray(array, length);
```

or you can pass the length as a pointer, which will reflect the canges:

```
void removeDuplicateInArray(int *array, int *plength) ...
{
    int length = *plength;

    // use and modify length as above

    *plength = length;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
removeDuplicateInArray(array, &length);
```

I prefer the second variant, because it doesn't allow you to accidentally forget about the return value.

The garbage value you see is shifted in from beyond the array's bounds, because you loop up to `k < length` and access athe element at index `k + 1`, which might be `length`, which is one element beyond the array.

Comment: I don't think you need those `void`s before the function name when you call the function.

Comment: @M Oehm this means that if i use  a pointer (int *lenght) i will have to use cast "error: comparison between pointer and integer [-Werror]|"

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Oh, I've left them there for the compiler to find them. (Fixed, thanks!)

Comment: you could return the new length

Comment: @Michi: No, you won't need casts. But you must use `*length` inside the function where you usually would use just `length`.

Comment: @MOehm now i get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" instead of garbage., please show me a complete removeDuplicate function change

Comment: @Michi: I've added a function body for your function. Note that I've now called the pointer `plength` and made `length` a local variable, so that you can still use your code. If you don't feel comfortable with pointers yet, you can use the first variant.

Comment: @Michi: You apparently heed the warnings, which is good. But resist the temptation to fix or silent warnings with casts. Especially when you cast pointers to ints and vice versa, you're entering segfault territory.

Comment: @MOehm int length = *plength; did the job, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In `removeDuplicateInArray` pass the `length` by pointer so it will have the proper value later in the main `void removeDuplicateInArray(int *array, int *length)`.